# SQL Server - get rid of derived query in join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm interested in some suggestions with examples on how to 1)get rid of the derived query in the left outer join and 2)remove/consolidate the cte  cteSecType in the code below The derived query in the join chooses the minimum assistant_personnel_number out of a list; there can be multiple primary and  backup assistants associated with an employee . thx

```
WITH    cteAssistants ( executive_personnel_number, assistant_personnel_number, assistant_type, assign_role )
          AS ( SELECT   CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(JP.XA_asgn_emplid) = 1
                             THEN JP.XA_asgn_emplid
                             ELSE ''
                        END AS executive_personnel_number ,
                        JAP.emplid AS assistant_personnel_number ,
                        LAT1.FIELDVALUE AS assistant_type ,
                        LAT3.xlatshortname AS assign_role
               FROM     dbo.XA_ASGN_PRNT AS KAP
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.XA_ASSIGNMENTS AS KA ON JP.emplid = JAP.emplid
                                                          AND JP.effdt = JAP.effdt
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.XA_EMPLOYEES AS EXECT ON EXECT.EMPLID = JP.XA_ASGN_EMPLID
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.XA_EMPLOYEES AS ASST ON ASST.EMPLID = JAP.EMPLID
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.XLATITEM AS XLAT1 ON LAT1.fieldname = 'XA_ASGN_TYPE'
                                                          AND LAT1.fieldvalue = JAP.XA_asgn_type
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.XLATITEM AS XLAT3 ON LAT3.fieldname = 'XA_ASGN_ROLE'
                                                          AND LAT3.fieldvalue = JP.XA_asgn_role
               WHERE    JAP.effdt = ( SELECT    MAX(effdt)
                                      FROM      dbo.XA_ASGN_PRNT
                                      WHERE     emplid = JAP.emplid
                                                AND effdt <= GETDATE()
                                    )
                        --Return data only when both executive and assistant are still active; null is for Floaters
                        AND ( EXECT.HR_STATUS = 'A'
                              OR EXECT.HR_STATUS IS NULL
                            )
                        AND ASST.HR_STATUS = 'A'

                        AND ( JAP.XA_asgn_type = 'F'

                              OR ( JAP.XA_asgn_type IN ( 'A', 'AF' )
                                   AND JP.XA_asgn_person = 'Y'
                                 )
                            )
             ),
        cteSecType ( assistant_personnel_number, SecType )
          AS ( SELECT   assistant_personnel_number ,
                        assistant_type AS SecType
               FROM     cteAssistants 
               GROUP BY assistant_type ,
                        assistant_personnel_number
             )
    SELECT  EMP.XA_NETWORK_ID AS network_id ,
            EMP.XA_EMPLID AS empid ,
            EMP.XA_EMPLID AS employeeNumber ,
            EMP.XA_FIRST_NAME AS first_name ,
            EMP.XA_LAST_NAME AS last_name ,
            SECRES.SecType AS SecType ,
            AsstInfo.XA_fml_pref_name AS PrimaryAssistant_FML ,
            AsstInfo.XA_network_id AS PrimaryAssistant_Newtork_ID ,
            AsstInfo.XA_EMPLID AS PrimaryAssistant_EmpID ,
            AsstInfo.XA_phone_ext AS PrimaryAssitant_Extension
    FROM    dbo.XA_EMPLOYEES AS EMP
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.XA_EMPLOYEES AS MGR ON EMP.supervisor_id = MGR.emplid
            LEFT OUTER JOIN cteSecType AS SECRES ON CAST(CAST(SECRES.assistant_personnel_number AS INT) AS VARCHAR(11)) = EMP.XA_EMPLID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT    executive_personnel_number AS AttorneyID ,
                                        MIN(assistant_personnel_number) AS AssistantID
                              FROM      cteEmployeeAssistants AS A
                              WHERE     ( assign_role = 'Primary' )
                              GROUP BY  executive_personnel_number
                            ) AS ASST ON ASST.AttorneyID = EMP.XA_EMPLID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.XA_EMPLOYEES AS ASSTINFO ON ASSTINFO.XA_EMPLID = ASST.AssistantID
    WHERE   ( EMP.HR_STATUS = 'A' )
            AND ( EMP.PER_ORG IN ( 'EMP', 'CWR' ) )
            AND ( ISNULL(EMP.XA_NETWORK_ID, '') <> '' )
```

GO

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are trying to address?  Performance?  Readability?  If all you want is a simpler query, you could separate this query into different Views and join them together piece by piece.

Comment: You seem to know what a CTE is, so you could just create another CTE for it.

Comment: This code is part of a new view which has already been consolidated quite a bit to draw from the base tables instead of other views. The issue i'm trying to address is our standard of not using derived queries in the joins and reduce cte's to only when absolutely needed. thx